# Specifying default arguments for main

Tags: kotlin

What am I doing wrong here?

```
fun main(args: Array<String> = arrayOf("abc")) {
    val a = args[0]
}
```

compiles fine but:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

I want to make it optional to have an argument and supply a default value if none was specified

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This probably does not work because of how the underlying Java platform works and how Kotlin translates default arguments to something the JVM can understand. You could say it's a bug in Kotlin...

The Java virtual machine looks for a method with the following signature to run your program (this is Java):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

Note that default argument values do not exist in Java, so if you declare a method with default values in Kotlin, the Kotlin compiler generates multiple methods in the Java byte code that will look like this when converted to Java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // the normal main method
}

// generated because you have a method with default values
public static void main() {
    main(new String[]{ "abc" });
}
```

When you run the program, the JVM will still look for the method with the `String[] args` argument. It will ignore the method with no arguments, that was generated for the Kotlin `main` method with default arguments.

So it's always going to call the `String[] args` version, even if there are no arguments on the command line - leading to the error that you get.

Workaround: Don't use default values for the `main` method; check if arguments were given inside the method:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val realArgs = if (args.size > 0) args else arrayOf("abc")

    // work with realArgs
}
```

Comment: Great explanation! I don't believe we can say it's a bug in Kotlin, though. No arguments on the command line means an array of 0 elements, not an absence of array. So even if we were calling this `main` function from Kotlin code supporting default arguments, I would still believe this natural to call the function with an empty array as parameter.

Comment: @Joffrey Yes - whether or not you'd call this a bug depends on how you interpret what "no arguments on the command line" means.

Comment: `main()` won't be generated unless you use `@JvmOverloads` (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#overloads-generation). Instead calls to `main()` without arguments _from Kotlin code_ will become `main(methodReturningDefaultArgsValue())` (don't know what name will be used for the method). Since there's no Kotlin code calling `main()`, this doesn't matter. And if `@JvmOverloads` is used, it'll still only affect Java code explicitly calling `main()`.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's a question of signature the JVM's search for `main` methods: a `main` method should have one parameter of `String[]` type, and this parameter receives value(s) from CLI; if the CLI does not provide any parameter, the `main` method receives a `new String[0]`, which causes the error you're experiencing.

I think you can solve the problem slightly changing the approach:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(args)
    val a = args.getOrElse(0) {"abc"}
    println(a)
}
```

should work for your scenario: if there is no parameter with index `0` `a` gets the default value you passed (as a lambda) to `getOrElse`.